# Asymptotic expansion on the following integral of exponential function

Tags: st.statistics, asymptotics, stochastic-calculus

I wish to obtain the asymptotic for the following integral
$$
\int_{r: \|r\|\le 1} \exp(M\cdot a^Tr) \, dr,
$$
where $a$ is a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\|\cdot\|$ is a general norm function and $M\to\infty$. I know the maximizer of $\max\{a^Tr: \|r\|\le 1\}$ would be $\|a\|_*$. However, still confused how to simplify such kind of integral.

Comment: what is $M$, a scalar, a vector, a matrix?

Comment: The asymptotic will **very much** depend on the norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: Here M is a scalar

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$The logarithmic asymptotic is given by the formula
$$I(M):=\int_{r\colon\|r\|\le1}\exp(M\,a^Tr)\,dr=\exp(M(1+o(1))\,\|a\|_*) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
(as $M\to\infty$), where $\|a\|_*:=\sup\{a^T r\colon r\in B_1\}\ne0$ and $B_R:=\{r\colon\|r\|<R\}$.

Indeed, the unit ball $B_1$ is a nonempty bounded open set. So, $m:=|B_1|\in(0,\infty)$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue measure. Similarly, for any $\de\in(0,1)$, the set $A_\de:=B_1\setminus B_{1-\de}$ contains a nonempty open set, and hence $\ep_\de:=|A_\de|\in(0,m]\subset(0,\infty)$. Now write
$$I(M)\le\int_{B_1}\exp(M\,\|a\|_*)\,dr=\exp(M\,\|a\|_*)\,m$$
and
$$I(M)\ge\int_{A_\de}\exp(M\,a^Tr)\,dr
\ge\exp((1-\de)M\,\|a\|_*)\ep_\de.$$
Letting now $M\to\infty$, we get
$$I(M)\le\exp((1+o(1))M\,\|a\|_*)$$
and
$$I(M)\ge\exp((1-\de+o(1))M\,\|a\|_*),$$
for each $\de\in(0,1)$.
Thus, \eqref{1} follows. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am wondering if it is possible to derive a result that $I(M) = V(M) (1 + o(1))$, where $V(M)$ is a certain analytical function? In other words, the small $o(\cdot)$ notation should lie outside the exponent term.

Comment: @user497696 : As I said, this would very much depend on the norm. Also, I think in general there will be no such asymptotic at all, because an arbitrary convex function can behave weirdly in any neighborhood of a given point.